# Representing GIS data in ArcScene so it looks like bar and circle?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst, arcscene

Is there a way to represent GIS data in ArcScene  so it looks like a bar and circle?

[image]

I can only either get the bar by extruding my points but I wanted a circle on top. I don't know how to get my circles to float to the top of my bars.